# Blazor Error CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' IIS ABP.io

Tags: iis, blazor-client-side, abp

We develop an web app based on abp.io V4.0.0 framework, on IDE all runs OK..

But when we publish on IIS, we get this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://WebAPIUrlRoute:41124/connect/userinfo' from origin
'https://WebAppUrlRoute:41123' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

On appsettings.Json we put this URL => https://WebAppUrlRoute:41123
The code on WebApp to star CORS Services is this:

```
 private void ConfigureCors(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        context.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins(
                        configuration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                            .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                            .ToArray()
                    )
                    .WithAbpExposedHeaders()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
    }
```

The process to make log in is complete, because its run on web api's service but when Service return to Web app show me that error on console log's.

My JSON File settings (apppsettings.json) has something like this:

```
"App": {
"SelfUrl": "https://WebAPIUrlRoute:41124",
"CorsOrigins": "https://WebAppUrlRoute:41123"
```

}

Anybody can help me, please...

Comment: perhaps edit you post to show the relevant (or part thereof) `appsettings.json` file

Comment: I add part of my json file settings

Comment: try adding some temporary code to see what was actually being built for the cors - so you can at least debug it a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding app.UseCors() in the module OnApplicationInitialization method.

```
app.UseCors()
```